# Why Wont my .inc file show up on my .shtml file? (SSI)

Tags: html, xhtml, ssi

So I created a simple little .inc file, but for some reason it will not show up when I open the shtml file. I think that the actual .inc file is correct, but for some reason I just can't get it to show up when I open this file. Is there something that I am leaving out here? I was taught that you just had to include that one line of code within the body tags to get it to show up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Homepage </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<!--#include virtual="menu.inc"-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're testing locally, the most likely cause is that you haven't actually enabled your server to run SSI.

You can test this with:

```
<!--#config timefmt="%A" --> <!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
```

If that outputs the current day, you're set up. If not, you haven't configured SSI.

To permit SSI on your server, you must have the following directive either in your `httpd.conf` file, or in a `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +Includes
```

You would also need one of two additional things...

Either add the following to your `httpd.conf` / `.htaccess` file to allow `.shtml` files to be include:

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

Or alternatively, use the [XBitHack](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#xbithack) directive:

```
XBitHack on
chmod +x pagename.html
```

Hope this helps! :)